# mouseenter and leave show and hide but override when clicked

Tags: jquery, click, mouseevent, show

I have a jquery script where if user mouseenter, element is .show(), and mouseleave, element is .hide(). But what if you have the user click, and want to show the element even if the mouse leaves? How would you override the mouseleave, when user clicks?

My script goes something like this

```
    $('.block').live("mouseenter",function(){
                var id= $(this).attr('id');
                $('#'+id).show();
                $(this).click(function(){
                      //show? is this how it works? not sure where click should go.
        });

            }).live("mouseleave",function(){
            var id= $(this).attr('id');
            $('#'+id).hide();

        });
```

How do I deal with click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unbind the mouseleave event handler when the user clicks the div

```
$(function() {

    $('.block').live("mouseenter", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + id).show();
        $(this).click(function() {
            //show? is this how it works? not sure where click should go.
        });

    }).live("mouseleave", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + id).hide();

    }).live("click",function(){
         $(this).unbind("mouseleave"); 
         $(this).removeClass('block');  //this was added
    });
});
```

Try could even try using using `$('.block').hover(function(){},function(){})` instead of handling the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events individually.Also if possible use delegation instead of using `live`. But that is just an opinion not related to your question.

Edit : with delegate . Note for this to work the div.blocks need to be as

```
<div id="container">
<div class="block">
<div class="block">
</div>



$('#container').delegate('.block', 'mouseenter', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.msg').html('I entered :' + id);

});
$('#container').delegate('.block', 'mouseleave', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.msg').html('I came out of :' + id);

});
$('#container').delegate('.block', 'click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.msg').html('I entered and clicked :' + id);
    $(this).unbind("mouseleave");
    $(this).removeClass('block');
});
```

Also you would need to remove the class block from the div which is clicked so as to counter the effect of `.live` or `.delegate`

Comment: It is probably more semantically correct to use `.die` instead of `.unbind`. However, this one works too :)

Comment: can you post an example of using delegation? It seems like my click does not work

Comment: let me know if the solution works now.. you would have to remove the class block from the div to counter the effects of live and delegate (which ever you want to use)

Answer (score 1):

You can use .unbind to remove the event handlers for "mouseleave". Also, using $(this) will refer to the element that fired the event, regardless of whether the event handler is attached to the classname, so you don't need the code that fetches the id.

```
$('.block').live("mouseenter",function(){

    $(this.)show();

}).live("mouseleave",function(){

    $(this).hide();

}).live("click", function(){

    this.unbind("mouseleave");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's slightly nicer to use classes to represent a state so you can style the elements accordingly. Though this does query the dom a little more, it's probably better than adding and removing events the whole time... This should do it:

```
    $('.link').live({
        mouseenter: function(){
            if(!$('.link.locked').length)
            {
                $(this).show();
            }
        }, 
        mouseleave: function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass('locked'))
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        },
        click: function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('locked');
        }
    });
```

BTW this the following

```
$(this).show();
```

Is the same as

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$('#'+id).show();
```

You managed to take an extra step... ? If you're not hiding/showing `this` then this is probably the wrong aproach, if you're hiding/showing a different element make sure you modify the code accordingly.